# Prometheus scrape using oauth2 results in "Unresolved variable: request.header.Authorization"

Tags: oauth-2.0, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

Recently added to prometheus the possibility to scrape targets using [oauth2](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#oauth2) authentication. And when using it I get the following error, it looks like the **Authorization** is not being sent.

```
    Get "http://target.foo.bar.net:80/my-service/metrics": oauth2: cannot fetch token: 500 Internal Server Error Response: {"fault":{"faultstring":"Unresolved variable : request.header.Authorization","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.basicauthentication.UnresolvedVariable"}}}
```

This is my configuration from prometheus.yml.

Where `token_url` is the address of my service that authenticates my `client_id` and `client_secret` and responds with a token. And `targets` my endpoint where I will monitor authenticating using the token.

```
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: my-service
      metrics_path: /target.foo.bar/metrics
      oauth2:
        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
        client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET'
        token_url: 'https://token-foo-generator.com/oauth/v1/token'
        endpoint_params:
          grant_type: 'client_credentials'
      static_configs:
        - targets:
            - target.foo.bar.net
```

As this was recently added to prometheus(like two months ago), I found little documentation on this and I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar technology stack, mines is based on `Ubuntu`,`Keycloak`, `Prometheus` and `spring boot` with a connection type of oauth-2.0. Its not the same, but some of the issues may be similar.

My first problem was that my version of Ubuntu had an ancient version of `Prometheus`, which did not include the oauth support. Installing version 2.33, which has oauth-2.0 stuff included resolved this issue. The version of  `Prometheus` is returned by the '--version' flag.
To get  `Keycloak`  to support a 'credit_credentials' its necessary to create a service_account, to support this, you must created a role of 'prometheus' and assigned it to the  service_account

The `Prometheus` config file `prometheus.yml` is set up is as follows

```
- job_name: "keycloak"
metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
scrape_interval: 5s
oauth2:
  client_id: 'rm-config-server'
  client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  token_url: 'http://localhost:8085/auth/realms/BootAdmin/protocol/openid-connect/token'
  endpoint_params:
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
static_configs:
  - targets: ["localhost:8888"]
```

This says get a token from `Keycloak` at address localhost:8085 with a realm of `BootAdmin` and make a request for  `Prometheus` at the address localhost:8888.  Where the XXXXX is a replacement for the actually value that `Keycloak` generates for a client secret.

To see what  `Keycloak`  generates, do a

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8085/auth/realms/BootAdmin/protocol/openid-connect/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=rm-config-server' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' --data-urlencode 'scope=email' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

The result is token, if you paste the string following access_token into the debug box of [JWT token decode](https://jwt.io) it will decode what `Keycloak` actually sent.  In my case it sent a token with prometheus role defined.

The spring boot application includes in its  KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter method includes the line

```
requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("prometheus")).hasRole("PROMETHEUS")
```

Which says if you find a request for an endpoint ending in the string  'prometheus' with a role of 'ROLE_PROMETHEUS' accept it. My initial attempt here include the string  '/acutator/prometheus' as the endpoint  which resulted in an error.

By setting the logging level in spring boot to maximum and running Prometheus as `prometheus --config.file prometheus.yml --log.level=debug`

It was possible to see requests been made and 200 responses been returned.

Accessing the normal `Prometheus` port of 9090, under pulls downs of `Status/Service Discover` should show the name of the job if the connection has worked, in case it showed the job name of keycloak

In summary

1. Make sure your version of `prometheus` includes the software support for oauth connections.
2. Make sure what ever token generating software your using is return what you expect it to. Do decode its output. In my case it several attempts to get the right information in to the generated token, something most client software will not display for security reasons.
3. Spy on the conversation that `prometheus` is having with the debug option.
4. Remove all 'jobs' except the one that you are attempting to work on in the prometheus.yml.